# react router can't redirect to protected route (just changes the URL)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

In my react application I'm trying to redirect to dashboard after than login, but since than protected route name is not 'route', react router can't detect it as a route and just changes the URL.
I've been checked unprotected and simple routes such 'register' and that loaded like a charm on redirect process.

It seems react router 4 can't detect protected route as a route.

here are my routes in app.jsx:

```
const routes = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
            <Route path="/resetpassword" component={ResetPassword}/> 
            <RestaurantAuthRoute path="/dashboard" component={RPDashboard}/>        
            <RestaurantAuthRoute path="/dashboard/addfood" component={RPAddFood}/>        
        </div>
    </Router>
);
```

RestaurantAuthRoute.jsx:

```
var {connect} = require('react-redux');
var loginAuth = require('../api/loginAuth');
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actions from 'actions';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class RestaurantAuthRoute extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        var mytoken = localStorage.getItem('token');
        var that = this;    

        loginAuth.restaurantAuthCheck(mytoken).then( function(res){
            if(res.success == true){
                that.props.actions.setRestaurantAuth(true);
            }
            else if(res.success == false){
                that.props.actions.setRestaurantAuth(false);
            }
        });

    }


    render() {
        if(this.props.restaurantLog.status == true || this.props.restaurantLog.status == false){
            const { component: Component, restaurantLog, ...rest } = this.props;
            return (
                <Route {...rest} render={props => {
                    return restaurantLog.status
                        ? <Component {...props} />
                        : <Redirect to="/login" />
                }} />
            )    
        }
        else{
            return(<p>wait</p>)
        }
    }
}



function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    return{
        restaurantLog: state.logRestaurantState
    }
}

function MapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return{
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    MapDispatchToProps
)(RestaurantAuthRoute);
```

Comment: It is true syntax and simple routes working (router element must have one signle children).

Comment: can you add the implementation of RestaurantAuthRoute

Comment: RestaurantAuthRoute #added